# ChartKick gem passing through hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, charts, chartkick

I'm using the [ChartKick ruby gem](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) and wondering how I can pass in a parameter to resize the percentage font sizes and also hide the text of the second percentage.

```
 <%= pie_chart({"Watched" => 45.9, nil => 54.1}, :library => {:colors => ["#1ac6ff", "#ECECEB"], :legend => 'none', :fontSize => '35px'}) %>
```

I was referencing [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) and could hide both percentages by doing `pieSliceText: 'none'` but couldn't figure out how to have that only apply to the second percentage. the fontSize parameter isn't resizing the font either. any suggestions?

I want the percentage text on the right side in blue side to be bigger, and the percentage text in left side to be hidden.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fontSize` has to be specified as a number. Try `:fontSize => 10`,  `:fontSize => 20`, etc, for making the percentage text on the right side in blue side to be bigger.

Doesn't look like it is possible to completely hide one of the percentage text while displaying another one.

The following makes it show the two texts with different fonts. Unfortunately, setting 0 as the font size doesn't work.

```
<%= pie_chart({"Watched" => 45.9, nil => 54.1}, 
    :library => {
       :legend => 'none', 
       :slices => [
         {color: "#1ac6ff", textStyle: {fontSize: 20}}, 
         {color: "#ECECEB", textStyle: {fontSize: 10}}
       ]
    }) 
%>
```

[image: different size fonts]

You could hide the whole slice by setting the color as `transparent` as follows:

```
<%= pie_chart({"Watched" => 45.9, nil => 54.1}, 
       :library => {
         colors: ["#1ac6ff", "transparent"],
         legend: 'none',    
         fontSize: 20
  }) 
%>
```

[image: transparent slice]

Comment: Weird, when I try that my font won't show up at all.

Comment: It generates this HTML<div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 310px; left: 380px; white-space: nowrap; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">45.91 (45.9%)</div>

Comment: guess I can't use the same syntax I was using. Using your syntax with the full block works. thank you

Comment: `fontSize=35` wasn't showing anything for me either; I am guessing there is an upper limit on the font size that can be used.